Place calendar below input with "react-datepicker" library
I use the react-datepicker library to select dates from the calendar in my react project with typescript.
I would like to display the calendar always at the bottom of the input.
This is how I visualize it: 
Doing some research it would be useful to modify the "popperPlacement" and "popperModifiers" properties, but the solutions are on older versions of the library.
I use the latest versions of "react-datepicker" (6.8.0) and "@types/react-datepicker" (6.2.0)
An example from the doc: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-configure-floating-ui-properties.
But I can't figure out how to use "popperModifiers" and the property: "popperPlacement=bottom" alone doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1246

@dippas
I had already checked this post but the proposed solutions are no longer applicable for the latest versions of the library.
Try using it with the latest version of the library and using typescript

() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      popperClassName="some-custom-class"
      popperPlacement="top-end"
      popperModifiers={[
        {
          name: "myModifier",
          fn(state) {
            // Do something with the state
            return state;
          },
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

So this is the example from the website. On the website, if I change this to popperPlacement="bottom" an keep both popperClassName="some-custom-class" and popperModifiers={[{...}]} and that seemed to work.
So, try copying exactly this into your codebase somewhere and see if it works by itself. This will tell you if its a library problem or an issue with your codebase. It's possible there are other properties you have set which will effect this or there is some css being applied which affects this. (You could use the browser tools to see what css is being applied to the element to see if this is the case)
Possibly you may need to update the libary version to latest.

Unfortunately in my case it doesn't work
